# how to create a relation model with forms?

Tags: python, django

Hey i need to create a model from form. It's different way if i need to create a some another model, that have a relations with created object model from form. its must work like that -> i come on site, get form for create a model object and save new object. an then -> i have another model with relations with model from form. and i need, to create relation model object automaticly - when django taked new object from forms.

tried any can help me. i make it this way, but this time i have problem. -> i have manytomany field in my relation model, and i have manytomany field ->users from form. and i cant create a relation model with this instance :(  Traceback:

```
TypeError at /ru/center/add/

Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use users_center.set() instead.
```

but i tired to try it(( help please, how i may do it?

views.py

```
for x in form['users_center'].data:

    name_center = form['name_center'].data
    fullname_center = form['fullname_center'].data
    ogrn = form['ogrn_center'].data
    head_center = form['head_center'].data  # user id
    many_users = form['users_center'].data
    user_center = x  # user id

new_center = Center.objects.create(name_center=name_center,
                                   fullname_center=fullname_center,
                                   ogrn_center=ogrn,
                                   head_center=User.objects.get(id=head_center),
users_center=User.objects.get(id=int(x)))

new_center.save()
```

models.py

```
users_center = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                          related_name='center',
                                          # through=CenterDetails,
                                          default=None, blank=True,
                                          verbose_name=_("Сотрудники"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. **Do not link to code** - reduce it as far as possible to replicate the error and [edit] your question. After pasting your code as [mcve], select it and CTRL+K to format as code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a join table implied by the many-to-many relationship between two models. The error is letting you know that you must set the relationship after creating a User object instead of trying to assign the relationship while creating the User object. You can use `set()` or `add()` to do this.
So try doing:

```
new_center = Center.objects.create(
  name_center=name_center,
  fullname_center=fullname_center,
  ogrn_center=ogrn,
  head_center=User.objects.get(id=head_center),
)

users_center=User.objects.get(id=int(x))
new_center.users_center.add(users_center)
```

Additionally it may be useful to rename your many to many field as a plural to indicate the relationship. Maybe `users_centers` instead. Since it seems like users can have many centers, and centers can have many users. That's up to you though, not required for it to work.

Comment: documentation for reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/